# Java - How to search for a value in the list of objects

Tags: java, list, optimization, arraylist, java-stream

For example i have list, class and methods:

```
List<Client> myClient = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
public class Client {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String cID;
    boolean subscription = false;
}
```

```
public String activateSubscription(String customerID){
    for( Client myCustomer: myClient ){
        if( myCustomer.cID == customerID ){
            myCustomer.setSubscription();
            break;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public void getClientName(String customerID){
    String nameCustomer = null;

    for( Client myCustomer: myClient ){
        if( myClient.clientID == customerID ){
            nameCustomer = myCustomer.getFullName();
            break;
        }
    }

    return nameCustomer;
}

public int getNumberOfSubsrtipion(){
    int count = 0;

    for( Client myCustomer: myClient ){
        if( myCustomer.getSubscription ){
            count += 1;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

I'm new to Java, and I wondering if it's possible to simplify this code?

Maybe there's a simpler way to count subscribed customers and searching for customers by ID?

Comment: why `getClientName` returns nothing ?

Comment: `myCustomer.cID == customerID` is not doing what you thing it does.

Comment: `getClientName` does not return anything, it should return a `String`.

Comment: *"Maybe there's a simpler way to count subscribed customers and searching for customers by ID?"*  Well, for getting total number of subscriptions, you could have a variable something like `static int totalSubscriptions = 0;` and increment it each time `activateSubscription` *acutally changes* the subscription to `true`.

Comment: You could also improve performance by using a `HashMap`. But, since you seem to be very new, it might be better to learn about that later.

Comment: One thing you can do is eliminate compiler errors. In a method that has a `void` return type, there cannot be something after the `return` keyword.

Comment: == only works with primitive types.  == on object types is the identity check.  Strings are objects.  you will want to use equals with objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Streams` you can simplify it yes

```
public long getNumberOfSubscription() {
    return myClient.stream().filter(Client::getSubscription).count();
}

public void activateSubscription(String customerID) {
    myClient.stream().filter(c -> c.getcID().equals(customerID))
            .findFirst()
            .ifPresent(client -> client.setSubscription(true));
}

public String getClientName(String customerID) {
    return myClient.stream().filter(c -> c.getcID().equals(customerID))
            .map(Client::getFullName).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: imho the `orElseThrow` combined with `catch` should be replaced with `map(Client::getFullName).orElse(null);`